# Does a query 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:...' require 'Marketing Developer Platform'?

Tags: rest, api, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

An address https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:10239645&oauth2_access_token= + valid access token returns:

```
{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET-owners /shares","status":403}
```

A company for which I use the query is verified in my LinkedIn app.

Does the query 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:...' require the product 'Marketing Developer Platform' added to a LinkedIn application?

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/marketing-permissions-migration?context=linkedin/marketing/context a permission 'r_organization_social' is required to retrieve member’s organizations' posts. Is the product 'Marketing Developer Platform' required to obtain the permission 'r_organization_social' and a permission to use the query 'v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:...'? Should these permissions be obtained in a different way? If so, in which way?

I am trying to add the product 'Marketing Developer Platform' to my LinkedIn app. A status of this product is 'Review in progress'. Can I speed up adding this product to my app? Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

No required. For organization shares, you may only retrieve shares for organizations for which the authorized member is an administrator.

Are you the admin of "urn:li:organization:10239645" ??

Comment: Do you have and details or links on which endpoints to use to do this. I have been told by LinkedIn API support that they do not allow feeds/shares to be accessed outside of LinkedIn. I am an administrator of my Companies page on LinkedIn